# How to log to Powershell console from Workflow Job

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-workflow

I have a Powershell workflow. I need to log data to Console so that the progress of the workflow is clearly visible. Till now I used `Log-Verbose` to achieve this. When I execute this workflow with `-Verbose` switch, verbose logs are displayed on the console as expected.

```
workflow Test-Workflow
{
    Log-Verbose "Inside Test-Workflow"
}

Test-Workflow -Verbose
```

Now I need to use checkpoints inside the workflow. To take advantage of checkpoints, I need to run the workflow as a `Job`.

```
Test-Workflow -Verbose -AsJob
```

When I do so, I no longer see the verbose logs on the console. I know I can write to a file or write the logs as events but I would really like to write them to the console. Let me know if this is possible and how.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you have discovered a solution to this by now but you can use:

```
Write-Output "I will print to the console"
```

According to [MSDN: Write-Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output):

> Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console.